# Z-module isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let  n,d be positive integer numbers such that d|n. Show that  $<\frac{n}{d}>$/$<n>$ Is isomorphic as a module to $\mathbb{Z}_{d}$

Comment: What have you tried?  Perhaps you can define a map sending one group to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Bbb Z$-modules are just abelian groups.

You can try to find a homomorphism $<n/d> \to \mathbb Z_d$ with kernel $<n>$ and apply the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: $<n/d> \to \mathbb Z_d$ $k=x.n/d |\to x$ works. Am l right?